# What is the formula for $n^{th}$ derivative of $ \sin^{-1} x, \quad \tan^{-1} x,\quad \sec x \quad \text{and}\quad \tan x$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Are there formulae for the nth derivatives of the following functions?

$1)\quad$ $sin^{-1} x$

$2)\quad$ $tan^{-1} x$

$3)\quad$ $sec x$

$4)\quad$ $tan x$

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to determine the Taylor series at zero for these functions, you do not need formulae for the nth derivative.

Answer (score 11):

For $\arcsin(x)$, the $n$-th derivative is a hypergeometric function, see [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/ArcSin/20/02/). In terms of Legendre polynomial:
$$
\frac{\partial ^n\sin ^{-1}(z)}{\partial z^n}=\frac{(-i)^{n-1} (n-1)! }{\left(1-z^2\right)^{n/2}} P_{n-1}\left(\frac{i z}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}\right)
$$

For $\arctan(x)$, see [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/ArcTan/20/02/). Here is a nice representative:
$$
\frac{\partial ^n\tan ^{-1}(z)}{\partial z^n}=\frac{1}{2} \left(i (-1)^n (n-1)!\right) \left((z-i)^{-n}-(z+i)^{-n}\right)
$$

For the tangent, the [answer](http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Tan/20/02/0003/) involved Stirling numbers of the second kind:
$$
\frac{\partial ^n\tan (z)}{\partial z^n}=-i^{n+1} 2^n (i \tan (z)-1+\delta _n) \sum _{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k k! }{2^k} \, \mathcal{S}_n^{(k)} \, \left(i \tan (z)+1\right)^k
$$

Results for $\sec(x)$ can be found [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Sec/20/02/).

Comment: ...and a tiny piece of advice for the OP: the [DLMF](http://dlmf.nist.gov/) and the [Wolfram Functions site](http://functions.wolfram.com/) really should be your first stops for answering questions like these.

Answer (score 3):

A [related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193702/find-an-expression-for-the-n-th-derivative-of-fx-ex2). See Chapter 6 in this [book](https://www.morebooks.de/store/bookprice_offer/show?token=b5ec76ad826b4d3a6608ef418df86ff97dd13938&auth_token=d3d3LnNjaG9sYXJzLXByZXNzLmNvbToxY2Q3MTg1NWJlNWFiMGExYWU5MTYxMWVkMDFhMmQyOQ==&locale=gb&srcid=0B4FXAHVyGS9KMGRiNDMyNDctMmQ1NS00MDI3LTk2OWEtNzc3N2ZlNDVmYjJm&hl=en_GB) for formulas for the nth derivative, $n$ is a non-negative integer, of $\tan(x)$ and $\sec(x)$ in terms of the [$\psi$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function)

\begin{equation}
{\tan}^{(n)} (z) = \frac{1}{{\pi}^{n+1}} \left({\psi}^{(n)} \left(
\frac{1}{2}+\frac{z}{\pi}\right) +  (-1)^{n+1} {\psi}^{(n)} \left(
\frac{1}{2}-\frac{z}{\pi}\right) \right)\,,
\end{equation}

\begin{align}\nonumber
{\sec}^{(n)}(z) = \frac{1}{ (2 \pi)^{ n + 1 } } &\left(
(-1)^{n}{\psi}^{(n)}\left( -\frac{2z-3\pi}{4\pi}\right) -
(-1)^{n}{\psi}^{(n)}\left( -\frac{2z-\pi}{4\pi}\right) \right.&
\\ \nonumber
& \left. - {\psi}^{(n)}\left( \frac{2z+\pi}{4\pi}\right) +
{\psi}^{(n)}\left( \frac{2z+3\pi}{4\pi}\right) \right) \,. &
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

One can find or derive all answers from results reviewed and surveyed in the paper

1. Feng Qi, Da-Wei Niu, Dongkyu Lim, and Yong-Hong Yao, *Special values of the Bell polynomials of the second kind for some sequences and functions*, Journal of Mathematical Analysis and Applications **491** (2020), no. 2, Paper No. 124382, 31 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jmaa.2020.124382.

and closely-related referecens therein. For expample, for $n\ge1$,

\begin{gather*}
\frac{\operatorname{d}^n(\arcsin x)}{\operatorname{d} x^n}=-\frac{\operatorname{d}^n(\arccos x)}{\operatorname{d} x^n}
=\frac{\operatorname{d}^{n-1}}{\operatorname{d} x^{n-1}}\biggl(\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}\,}\biggr)\\
=\frac1{(2x)^n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}2^{k+1}(2k-1)!! (n-k-1)!\binom{n-1}{k}\binom{k}{n-k-1}\biggl(\frac{x^2}{1-x^2}\biggr)^{k+1/2},\\
(\arctan z)^{(n)}
=\frac{(n-1)!}{(2z)^{n-1}}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^k\binom{k}{n-k-1}\frac{(2z)^{2k}}{(1+z^2)^{k+1}},\\
(\tan x)^{(n)}=-(\ln\cos x)^{(n+1)}
=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{k}\sum_{\ell=0}^k\binom{k}{\ell}\frac{(-1)^{\ell}}{(2\cos x)^\ell}
\sum_{q=0}^\ell\binom{\ell}{q}(2q-\ell)^{n+1} \cos\biggl[(2q-\ell)x+\frac{(n+1)\pi}2\biggr],
\end{gather*}
where $\lfloor{t}\rfloor$ denotes the floor function whose value equals the largest integer less than or equal to $t$.

**More references**

2. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4332741/
3. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4672327/
4. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4661266/
5. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4249446/