# Nth derivative of $\tan^m x$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, polynomials, derivatives

$m$ is positive integer,

$n$ is non-negative integer.

$$f_n(x)=\frac {d^n}{dx^n} (\tan ^m(x))$$

$P_n(x)=f_n(\arctan(x))$

I would like to find the polynomials that are defined as above

$P_0(x)=x^m$

$P_1(x)=mx^{m+1}+mx^{m-1}$

$P_2(x)=m(m+1)x^{m+2}+2m^2x^{m}+m(m-1)x^{m-2}$

$P_3(x)=(m^3+3m^2+2m)x^{m+3}+(3m^3+3m^2+2m)x^{m+1}+(3m^3-3m^2+2m)x^{m-1}+(m^3-3m^2+2m)x^{m-3}$

I wonder how to  find general formula of $P_n(x)$?

I also wish to know if any orthogonal relation  can be found for that polynomials or not?

Thanks for answers

EDIT:

I proved Robert Isreal's generating function. I would like to share it.

$$ g(x,z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{z^n}{n!} \dfrac{d^n}{dx^n} \tan^m(x)
= \tan^m(x+z)  $$

$$ \frac {d}{dz} (\tan^m(x+z))=m \tan^{m-1}(x+z)+m \tan^{m+1}(x+z)=m \sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{z^n}{n!} \dfrac{d^n}{dx^n} \tan^{m-1}(x)+m \sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{z^n}{n!} \dfrac{d^n}{dx^n} \tan^{m+1}(x)= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{z^n}{n!} \dfrac{d^n}{dx^n} (m\tan^{m-1}(x)+m\tan^{m+1}(x))=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{z^n}{n!} \dfrac{d^n}{dx^n} (\dfrac{d}{dx}(\tan^{m}(x)))=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{z^n}{n!} \dfrac{d^{n+1}}{dx^{n+1}} (\tan^{m}(x))=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{z^n}{n!} \dfrac{d^{n+1}}{dx^{n+1}} (\tan^{m}(x))$$

---

$$ \frac {d}{dz} ( \sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{z^n}{n!} \dfrac{d^n}{dx^n} \tan^m(x)
)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{z^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} \dfrac{d^n}{dx^n} \tan^m(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{z^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} \dfrac{d^n}{dx^n} \tan^m(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{z^{k}}{k!} \dfrac{d^{k+1}}{dx^{k+1}} \tan^m(x)$$

I also understood that it can be written for any function  as shown  below .(Thanks a lot to Robert Isreal)

$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{z^n}{n!} \dfrac{d^n}{dx^n} h^m(x)
= h^m(x+z)  $$

I also wrote $P_n(x)$ as the closed form shown below by using Robert Israel's  answer.

$$P_n(x)=\frac{n!}{2 \pi i}\int_0^{2 \pi i} e^{nz}\left(\dfrac{x+\tan(e^{-z})}{1-x \tan(e^{-z})}\right)^m dz$$

I do not know next step how to find if any orthogonal relation exist between the polynomials or not. Maybe second order differential equation can be found  by using the relations above.  Thanks for advice.

Comment: Note that the formula for the derivatives of the tangent [are already sufficiently complicated](http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Tan/20/02/0003/)... you might be able to combine that result with [Faà di Bruno's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula).

Comment: I added an answer explaining how to generally view the generating function derivation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the formula for nth derivative of arcsin x, arctan x, sec x and tan x?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75095/what-is-the-formula-for-nth-derivative-of-arcsin-x-arctan-x-sec-x-and-tan-x)

Comment: @J.M.: I checked the other question but I am looking for $tan^m(x)$ and related polinomials. Really it is not  duplicate. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't know if this will help:

The exponential generating function of $f_n(x)$ is
$$ g(x,z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{z^n}{n!} \dfrac{d^n}{dx^n} \tan^m(x)
= \tan^m(x+z) = \left(\dfrac{\tan(x)+\tan(z)}{1-\tan(x)\tan(z)}\right)^m $$
So the exponential generating function of $P_n(x)$ is
$$ G(x,z) = g(\arctan(x),z) = \left(\dfrac{x+\tan(z)}{1-x \tan(z)}\right)^m $$

Comment: Fantastic generating function you offered. Thanks. Can we find any orthogonal relation for polynoms via using that generating function? Maybe second order differential equation can be found by using it? Thanks for advice.

Comment: Could you please add or send a link  how we can prove that generating function works? Thanks a lot for helps

Answer (score 3):

The formula used to obtain the exponential generating function in Robert's answer is most easily seen with a little operator calculus. Let $\rm\:D = \frac{d}{dx}.\,$ Then the operator $\rm\,{\it e}^{\ zD} = \sum\, (zD)^k/k!\:$ acts as a linear shift operator $\rm\:x\to x+z\,\:$ on polynomials $\rm\:f(x)\:$ since

$$\rm {\it e}^{\ zD} x^n =\, \sum\, \dfrac{(zD)^k}{k!} x^n =\, \sum\, \dfrac{z^k}{k!} \dfrac{n!}{(n-k)!}\ x^{n-k} =\, \sum\, {n\choose k} z^k x^{n-k} =\, (x+z)^n$$

so by linearity $\rm {\it e}^{\ zD} f(x) = f(x\!+\!z)\:$ for all polynomials $\rm\:f(x),\:$ and also for all formal power series $\rm\,f(x)\,$ such that $\rm\:f(x\!+\!z)\,$ converges, i.e. where $\rm\:ord_x(x\!+\!z)\ge 1,\:$ e.g. for $\rm\: z = tan^{-1} x = x -x^3/3 +\, \ldots$

Comment: Very good operator. Great (+1). $\rm {\it e}^{\ zD} f(x) = f(x\!+\!z)\:$ : Does not it come from taylor series expansion? If you put the proof in your answer to inform reader, it could be perfect. It is just idea. Thanks a lot for answer and advice.

Comment: @Mathlover Yes, you can view it as an formal operational form of Taylor's formula. What further proof do you seek?

Comment: Your answer is ok. I understood what you mean in your answer. The generator is an application of Taylor's formula. Thanks

Comment: @Mathlover To be clear, it's not intended as a complete answer to your question but, rather, to complement Robert's answer.

Comment: :It is very clear. Thank you for your kindness

Answer (score 2):

I have been working on the problem of finding the nth derivative and the nth anti derivative of elementary and special functions for years. You are asking a question regarding a class of functions I have called "the class of meromorphic functions with infinite number of poles. I refer you to the chapter in my Ph.D. [thesis](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4FXAHVyGS9KMGRiNDMyNDctMmQ1NS00MDI3LTk2OWEtNzc3N2ZlNDVmYjJm/edit?hl=en_GB&pli=1) (UWO, 2004) where you can find some answers.

Comment: Your thesis on Fractional  Derivatives and Integrals are very useful ,  really good reference. Everything is very clear. There is example for nth derivative of $tan x$ in page 109. What about nth derivative of $tan^m x$. how can it be found? Thanks a lot for sharing and answer.

Comment: read from page 111-114, there I gave identities for some powers of tan(x) in terms of the Psi function, then it is a matter of differentiating the Psi function n times. Try to work it out for tan(x)^m.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: I read that part. you gave example till $m=5$ I could not reach general formula for $\tan^m(x)$. How to find  the patern  for general formula. It also looks  problem to find coeffiency of Psi function for general formula. Thanks for advice.

Comment: I am just wondering how you reached this problem?

Answer (score 1):

For $m \ge 1$, $P_n(x) = m x^{m-n} (1+x^2) R_n(x^2)$ where $R_n(t)$ is a polynomial of degree $n-1$ such that $R_1(t) = 1$ and 
$$ R_{n+1}(t) = 2 t (t+1) R'_n(t) + (m-n + (m-n+2) t) R_n(t)$$

Comment: looks Very nice result. Could you please give me clue how you got that result. thanks a lot for answer and advice.