# What is the simplest way to get Bernoulli numbers?

Tags: bernoulli-numbers

> On paper,  what is the simplest way to generate the Bernoulli fractions like $\frac{-1}{30} $and $\frac{7}{6}$?

Basically I'm trying to find and understand $B_n =$ (the stuff on this side) and I've seen something using $i$ and a contour integral with

$$\frac{z}{e^z-1}\frac{ dz}{z^{n+1}}$$

and I don't pretend to understand that at all.

$$B_n=\frac{n!}{2\pi \color{red}{i}}\color{red}{\oint}\color{red}{\frac{z}{\color{black}{e\color{red}{^z}}}}\color{red}{\frac{dz}{\color{black}{e^{n+1}}}}$$

$$B_n=\sum^n_{\color{red}{k}=0}\frac{1}{\color{red}{k}+1}\sum^\color{red}{k}_{\color{red}{v}=0}(-1)^\color{red}{v}\color{red}{\binom{k}{v}}\color{red}{v}^n$$

and then there's this variant I see used a lot called a Generating function where

$$B_n = \sum \frac{1}{k+1} \sum (-1)v (k\dots v)v^n$$

but I don't understand double sums either. I need to be able to reliably get Bernoulli numbers for Taylor series stuff like tangent and the hyperbolic variants. I've reached a limit of my understanding and made clear in red the parts I'm confused about. Like I get that the $i$ is imaginary and somehow related to rotation of $\pi$, probably positive and negative, but I don't know what the $d$ or $z$ mean in that equation.

In the second formula, I don't understand why it switched from $n$ to $k$, then from $k$ to $v$, though I suspect I'm supposed to increment $1:1$ increases in $n$ for $k$, which also increases my increments for $v$ by $1:1$ (creating a $\frac{+1}{-1}$ sequence) but I don't understand the vertical parentheses at all.
I'm not even going to pretend I took a class above calculus 1.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: Bernoulli numbers are tabulated in many places. Do you really need to calculate them, or just to read them from someone else's source?

Comment: i need to understand at least one equation i can use over and over to generate the bernoulli fractions. i think you guys call it an algorithm?

Comment: But why do you need to generate Bernoulli numbers, when other people have already tabulated them for you?

Comment: I believe he is trying to understand the significance

Answer (score 8):

The simplest way to calculate them, using very few fancy tools, is the following [recursive definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Recursive_definition):

$$B_n=1-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{n\choose k}\frac{B_k}{n-k+1}$$
in other words
$$B_n=1-{n\choose 0}\frac{B_0}{n-0+1}-{n\choose 1}\frac{B_1}{n-1+1}-\cdots -{n\choose n-1}\frac{B_{n-1}}{n-(n-1)+1}$$

Here, ${a\choose b}$ denotes a [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient).  So, we begin with $B_0=1, B_1=\frac{1}{2}$, and we can calculate $B_2$ using the above recursive definition.  That is, $B_2=1-{2\choose 0}\frac{B_0}{3}-{2\choose 1}\frac{B_1}{2}=1-\frac{1}{3}-2\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{2}=\frac{1}{6}$.

Now, with $B_2$ in hand, we can calculate $B_3$.  And so on.

Comment: i will play with this formula for several hours and hope it works and i dont get lost or make some glaring errors. Thank you!

Comment: Hope it works for what?

Comment: after a couple of hours i still don't get the parentheses (binom coeff.) like i get that (2/1) x (b1/2) = 2x(1/2 / 2) but then why does (2 / 0)x (b0 / 3) = 1/3? shouldn't 2 / 0 be an error? i dont know what a binomial coefficient is or understand combinatorics.

Comment: Binomial coefficients are not fractions; ${a\choose b}=\frac{a!}{b!(a-b)!}$.  If you don't know factorials or binomial coefficients, then perhaps you're not ready to understand Bernoulli numbers.  These are topics often taught in calc 1, near the end of the course, when learning about integration.

Comment: the numbers in the parentheses i do not understand. 1/3rd? where did that come from? if i ignore the parentheses i get the 1/3rd, but then i can't get the 2(1/2 / 2) if i ignore the ( 2 over 1) parentheses

Comment: ${2\choose 0}\frac{B_0}{3}=1\frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{3}$, since ${2\choose 0}=1$ and $B_0=1$.

Comment: so you are saying Binomial coefficients in addition to factorials are required? I only understand factorials, binomial coefficients are new to my list.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79910/discussion-between-tristian-and-vadim123).

Comment: I have tested the recursive method using Python and it works great, but I wonder why. The reason I am confused is, that you assumed that B0 = 1 and B1 = 1/2. However, B1 is -1/2 according to https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BernoulliNumber.html.
Using the recursive formula for B2 would yield B2 = 7/6 ?

Answer (score 2):

Chowla and Hartung, An "exact" formula for the $n$th Bernoulli number, Acta Arithmetica 22 (1972) 113-115, give the following formula, quoted in Comtet, Advanced Combinatorics: Let $$\phi_n={2(2^{2n}-1)(2n)!\over2^{2n-1}\pi^{2n}}\sum_{k=1}^{3n}k^{-2n}$$ and write $[x]$ for the greatest integer not exceeding $x$. Then $$B_{2n}=(-1)^{n-1}{1+[\phi_n]\over2(2^{2n}-1)}$$

You might also want to look at the [paper](https://wstein.org/projects/168/kevin_mcgown/bernproj.pdf), Kevin J. McGown, Computing Bernoulli numbers quickly.

My friend, David Harvey, at UNSW, may be the current record holder for fast computation of Bernoulli numbers for large values of $n$. See Richard P. Brent and David Harvey, Fast computation of [Bernoulli](https://arxiv.org/abs/1108.0286), Tangent and Secant numbers; see also A multimodular algorithm for computing Bernoulli numbers, Math. Comp. 79 (2010), no. 272, 2361–2370. MR 2684369 (2011h:11019)

Note: I've corrected an error I made in copying the formula out of Comtet.

Comment: you have a symbol that looks like pi there, , but you don't really mean 3.14159... do you? because that won't be accurate at all. Like if i say n = 1 i just get 2 over pi squared for phi sub one, and the equation doesn't produce a bernoulli fraction.

Comment: It  is pi, and for $\phi_1$ you should get $2/\pi^2$ times $\sum_1^3k^{-2}$. This leads to $B_2=1/6$, which is correct. The Chowla and Hartung paper is freely available on the web, you can check it out for yourself. I'm a little worried that the paper has $2^{2n}-1$ in the numerator of $\phi_n$, where I have $2^n-1$; I don't have Comtet at hand to check whether I miscopied.

Comment: I miscopied. Now corrected.

Comment: I tried this formula in a naive way without giving it enough thought. It sort of works for the first few Bernoulli numbers if you use finite precision ("double" perhaps) floating point arithmetic. 
It works like a charm if you determine up front how accurate you need to be. The number of bits you need may be estimated from the asymptotic formula for $B_{2n}$ along with the denominator which can be computed relatively quickly using Von Staudt/Clausen's thm.

Answer (score 2):

A straightforward method for generating the Bernoulli numbers is the [Akiyama-Tanigawa algorithm](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL3/KANEKO/AT-kaneko.pdf).

The algorithm goes like this:

> Start with the $0$-th row $1, \frac12, \frac13, \frac14 \ldots$
> and define the first row by $$1\cdot(1−\frac12), 2\cdot(\frac12 - \frac13), 3\cdot(\frac13 - \frac14) \ldots$$
> which produces the sequence $\frac12, \frac13, \frac14, \cdots$.
> Then define the next row by $$1\cdot(\frac12 - \frac13), 2\cdot(\frac13-\frac14), 3\cdot(\frac14-\frac15), \ldots$$ thus giving $\frac16, \frac16 \frac3{20}, \ldots $ as the second row. In general, denoting
> the $m$-th ( $m = 0, 1, 2, \ldots$) number in the $n$-th ($ n = 0, 1, 2, \ldots$) row by $a_{n,m}$, the $m$-th number in the $(n + 1)$-st row $a_{n+1,m}$ is determined recursively by $a_{n+1,m} = (m + 1) \cdot (a_{n,m} − a_{n,m+1})$.
> Then [...] the $0$-th component $a_{n,0}$ of each row (the “leading
> diagonal”) is just the $n$-th Bernoulli numbers $B_n$

The algorithm's output looks like:

[image]

and produces a value of $B_1 = \frac12$ in accordance with Bernoulli's derivation - the modern standard being $B_1 = -\frac12$.

Answer (score 0):

I sort of favor the [$\cot$ Laurent series](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2099213) as a starting point for calculating the Bernoulli numbers. Although the recursive formula still goes over all previous Bernoulli numbers, it includes $2$ per term, so only has half as many terms. If we let
$$y(x)=\cot x=\frac1x+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nB_{2n}2^{2n}x^{2n-1}}{(2n)!}=\frac1x+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nx^{2n-1}$$
Then
$$\begin{align}y^{\prime}&=-\frac1{x^2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(2n-1)a_nx^{2n-2}=-\csc^2x=-1-\cot^2x\\
&=-1-y^2=-1-\frac1{x^2}-2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nx^{2n-2}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_na_mx^{2n+2m-2}\end{align}$$
So
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(2n+1)a_nx^{2n-2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(2n+3)a_{n+1}x^{2n}=-1-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{m=1}^{n}a_ma_{n-m+1}\right)x^{2n}$$
Comparing coefficients of like powers of $n$ on both sides we get
$$a_1=-\frac13$$
$$a_{2n}=-\frac1{4n+1}\left(a_n^2+2\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}a_ma_{2n-m}\right)$$
$$a_{2n+1}=-\frac2{4n+3}\sum_{m=1}^{n}a_ma_{2n-m+1}$$
Sample program:

```
program bernoulli
   implicit none
   integer, parameter :: wp = kind(1.0d0)
   integer, parameter :: N = 10
   real(wp) a(N) ! a_n
   real(wp) b(N) ! b_2n
   real(wp) prefactor ! (-1)**n*(2n)!/2**(2n)
   integer i
   prefactor = 1
   do i = 1, N
      if(i == 1) then
         a(1) = real(-1,wp)/3
      else if(mod(i,2) == 0) then
         a(i) = -(a(i/2)**2+2*dot_product(a(1:i/2-1),a(i-1:i/2+1:-1)))/(2*i+1)
      else
         a(i) = -2*dot_product(a(1:i/2),a(i-1:i/2+1:-1))/(2*i+1)
      end if
      prefactor = -2*i*(2*i-1)*prefactor/4
      b(i) = prefactor*a(i)
      write(*,'(*(g0))') 'a(',i,') = ',a(i)
      write(*,'(*(g0))') 'B(',2*i,') = ',b(i)
   end do
end program bernoulli
```

Output:

```
a(1) = -.3333333333333333
B(2) = .1666666666666667
a(2) = -.2222222222222222E-01
B(4) = -.3333333333333333E-01
a(3) = -.2116402116402116E-02
B(6) = .2380952380952380E-01
a(4) = -.2116402116402116E-03
B(8) = -.3333333333333333E-01
a(5) = -.2137779915557693E-04
B(10) = .7575757575757573E-01
a(6) = -.2164404280806397E-05
B(12) = -.2531135531135530
a(7) = -.2192594785187377E-06
B(14) = 1.166666666666666
a(8) = -.2221460878997967E-07
B(16) = -7.092156862745096
a(9) = -.2250784651680898E-08
B(18) = 54.97117794486213
a(10) = -.2280515120459217E-09
B(20) = -529.1242424242421
```