# Getting $B_4$ from the recursive definition $B_n=1-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{n\choose k}\frac{B_k}{n-k+1}$

Tags: bernoulli-numbers

### Background

I've been learning the basics of Bernoulli numbers and this is a reference to [What is the simplest way to get Bernoulli numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2844290/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-get-bernoulli-numbers/2844293#2844293) and vadim123's succinct reply, where he stated:

> The simplest way to calculate them, using very few fancy tools, is the following [recursive definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Recursive_definition):
>
> $$B_n=1-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{n\choose k}\frac{B_k}{n-k+1}$$
> in other words
> $$B_n=1-{n\choose 0}\frac{B_0}{n-0+1}-{n\choose 1}\frac{B_1}{n-1+1}-\cdots -{n\choose n-1}\frac{B_{n-1}}{n-(n-1)+1}$$
>
> Here, ${a\choose b}$ denotes a [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient).  So, we begin with $B_0=1, B_1=\frac{1}{2}$, and we can calculate $B_2$ using the above recursive definition.  That is, $B_2=1-{2\choose 0}\frac{B_0}{3}-{2\choose 1}\frac{B_1}{2}=1-\frac{1}{3}-2\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{2}=\frac{1}{6}$.
>
> Now, with $B_2$ in hand, we can calculate $B_3$.  And so on.

I've decided to find $B_4$, but I wanted to see if my process was correct.

### My Attempt

Using the following recursive definition:

$$\begin{align*}
B_3&=1-{3\choose 0}\frac{B_0}{3-0+1}-{3\choose 1}\frac{B_1}{3-1+1}-{3\choose 2}\frac{B_2}{3-2+1}\\
&=1-\frac{1}{4}-3\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{3}-3\frac{\frac{1}{6}}{2}\\
&=0\\
\\
B_4&=1-{4\choose 0}\frac{B_0}{4-0+1}-{4\choose 1}\frac{B_1}{4-1+1}-{4\choose 2}\frac{B_2}{4-2+1}-{4\choose 3}\frac{B_3}{4-2+1}\\
&=1-\frac{1}{5}-4\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{4}-6\frac{\frac{1}{6}}{3}-{4\frac{0}{2}}\\
&=\boxed{-\frac{1}{30}}\\
\end{align*}$$

Would this process correct? Also, for higher Bernoulli numbers, say $B_{50}$, is there a better way to find them?

**Edit** @RobPratt, thank you kindly for correcting my errors! And, for providing the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this process is correct, but you had a couple errors that I just corrected for $B_3$.  Note that $B_n=0$ for odd $n>1$, so you can skip the calculation.  For efficient computation, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Efficient_computation_of_Bernoulli_numbers