# Expand $\tan z$ in terms of Bernoulli numbers

Tags: complex-analysis

Want to get this:
$$\tan z = \frac{1}{i}\frac{{{e^{iz}} - {e^{ - iz}}}}{{{e^{iz}} + {e^{ - iz}}}} = \frac{1}{i}\left( {1 - \frac{2}{{{e^{2iz}} - 1}} + \frac{4}{{{e^{4iz}} - 1}}} \right)$$
as a start.
Getting lost in the algebra

$$\frac{{{e^{iz}} - {e^{ - iz}}}}{{{e^{iz}} + {e^{ - iz}}}} = \frac{{{e^{iz}} + {e^{ - iz}} - 2{e^{ - iz}}}}{{{e^{ - iz}} + {e^{iz}}}} = \frac{{{e^{iz}} + {e^{ - iz}} - 2{e^{ - iz}}}}{{{e^{ - iz}} + {e^{iz}}}} = 1 - \frac{{2{e^{ - iz}}}}{{{e^{ - iz}} + {e^{iz}}}}$$

and also
$$\frac{{2{e^{ - iz}}}}{{{e^{ - iz}} + {e^{iz}}}} = \frac{2}{{{e^{2iz}} + 1}} = \frac{{ - 2 + 4}}{{{e^{2iz}} + 1}} = \frac{{ - 2}}{{{e^{2iz}} + 1}} + \frac{4}{{{e^{2iz}} + 1}}$$

Please someone, show me the right way.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2098941/bernoulli-numbers-taylor-series-expansion-of-tan-x

Comment: I have already seen this. I am asking specifically how to get the equation that I need to get started. Where is that in your proposed answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Work backwards! We have that
$$\begin{align} {1 - \frac{2}{{{e^{2iz}} - 1}} + \frac{4}{{{e^{4iz}} - 1}}}&=\frac{e^{4iz} - 1-2({e^{2iz}} + 1)+4}{{{e^{4iz}} - 1}}\\&=\frac{e^{4iz}-2e^{2iz}+1}{{e^{4iz}} - 1}=
\frac{(e^{2iz}-1)^2}{{e^{4iz}} - 1}\\&=\frac{e^{2iz}-1}{{e^{2iz}} + 1}=\frac{{{e^{iz}} - {e^{ - iz}}}}{{{e^{iz}} + {e^{ - iz}}}}.\end{align}$$
Supplement: since Bernoulli numbers are related to the expansion of $x/(e^x-1)$, we try to write the LHS in terms of functions like $1/(w^n-1)$ where $w=e^{iz}$,
$$\frac{{{e^{iz}} - {e^{ - iz}}}}{{{e^{iz}} + {e^{ - iz}}}}=\frac{w^2-1}{w^2 + 1}=1-\frac{2}{w^2 + 1}=1-\frac{2(w^2-1)}{w^4 - 1}\\=1-\frac{2(w^2+1)-4}{w^4 - 1}=1-\frac{2}{w^2 - 1}+\frac{4}{w^4 - 1}.$$

Comment: Thanks very helpful. Working backwards was ideal for verification and you have successfully answered the question, but as a supplemental question that follows how do you come up with the equation in the first place? Is it just a question of intuition and making an informed guess at a formula?

Comment: That is inspirational. Don't know why I didn't try the obvious substitution.