# Power series of $\tan(z)$

Tags: power-series

In the power series of

> $$\tan(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty }B_{2k}\frac{(-4)^k(1-4^k)x^{2k-1}}{(2k!)},$$ what is $B_{2k}$?

What's the mathematical expression of it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75095/what-is-the-formula-for-nth-derivative-of-arcsin-x-arctan-x-sec-x-and-tan-x) is a formula for finding the $n$th derivative of $\tan x$.

Answer (score 0):

$B_{2k}$ are Bernoulli numbers.  As they have numerous properties, a full treatment would be too lengthy to include as an answer, so I will refer you to here:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number