# Taylor Series Expansion for $\tan x$

Tags: trigonometry, taylor-expansion

I'm trying to determine the Taylor series expansion for $\tan x$:

I know that the $n$th derivative of the expansion must be the same as the $n$th derivative of the function.

Please help, I have no idea what to do.
:'(

Comment: Do you know the general form of a Taylor series?

Comment: But... You just explained what to do! Start finding those derivatives.

Comment: If you were *asked* to do this, it seems likely that you were only asked to find the first few terms. Go ahead and differentiate. You will not find a nice general formula.

Comment: Taylor expansion with what precision?

Comment: We need to use long division and tanx = sinx/cosx

Comment: @SOS Do you know the Taylor series for $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$?

Comment: Yes we do, in expansion and sigma form, where to from here?

Comment: See my [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75095/what-is-the-formula-for-nth-derivative-of-arcsin-x-arctan-x-sec-x-and-tan-x) and follow the link to see the technique.

Answer (score 4):

You may calculate derivative using $\tan=\sin/\cos$, as comment say. But you can also try the following strategy.

Let $\tan x=\sum_n a_nx^n$

you know that the derivative of $\tan x$ equals $1+(\tan x)^2$

So you know

$$\sum_n na_nx^{n-1}=1+(\sum_i a_ix^i)(\sum_i a_i x^i)=1+\sum_n(\sum_{k+m=n-1}a_ka_m)x^n$$

You also knonw that $\tan(-x)=-\tan x$, whence $a_n=0$ for $n$ even.

Using this you can arrange an inductive process to calculate the taylor expansion. (Namely, $a_{2k}=0, a_1=1, a_3=1/3,  a_5=2/15...$ and so on)

See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series 
and
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_numbers
for the explicit result

Comment: are x^n terms missing at the end of the equation?

Comment: @MycrofD yes! corrected, thanks