# If $Y=\tan^{-1} x$ , obtain an equation showing the relationship between $Y_{n+2}$ , $Y_{n+1}$ and $Y_{n}$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

This is what I did :

Since, $Y = \tan^{-1} x$, by differentiating we can get,

$Y_1 = \dfrac{1}{x^2 + 1},\\ Y_2 =\dfrac{ -2x}{(x^2 + 1)^2},\\ Y_3 = \dfrac{2 (3x^2 -1)}{ (x^2+1)^3}$

and so on...

As per the above pattern,  I know the formula for $Y_n$ will have $(x^2+1)^n$ in denominator but I'm unable to figure out the numerator.
Even If I get the formula for $Y_n$ , How am I supposed to proceed?
Please help. Thanks.

EDIT : I solved the question by using Leibniz theorem. Thanks to all who tried to help :)

Comment: Do you mean $$Y = tan^{-1} x,\\ Y_1 = \dfrac{1}{x^2 + 1},\\ Y_2 =\dfrac{ -2x}{(x^2 + 1)^2}\\, Y_3 = \dfrac{2 (3x^2 -1)}{ (x^2+1)^3}$$ ?

Comment: @Khosrotash yes

Comment: Does the notation $Y_n$ really mean the $n$th derivative of $Y$ here?

Comment: @pjs36 yes thats exactly what it means

Comment: For more terms, see http://www.opensky.ca/~jdhildeb/arctan/arctan_diff.html.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/a/75097/589.

Answer (score 0):

IF $$Y = \tan^{-1} x,\\ Y_1 = \dfrac{1}{x^2 + 1},\\ Y_2 =\dfrac{ -2x}{(x^2 + 1)^2}\\, Y_3 = \dfrac{2 (3x^2 -1)}{ (x^2+1)^3}$$
start by take derivation of $Y$
$$ Y = \tan^{-1} x\to Y'=Y_1 = \dfrac{1}{1+x^2 }$$ then try for $Y''$
and
$$ Y_1 = \dfrac{1}{x^2 + 1}\to Y_1'=\dfrac{0(x^2+1)-(2x)1}{(1+x^2)^2}=Y_2=Y''$$
can you go on  ?

Comment: Sir actually this is what I did. Since Y = tan^{-1}x , so I took the derivatives till Y_3. I have to find a general formula for Y_n so that I can proceed ahead. Please help me obtain Y_n

Comment: Do you have an answer sheet ? or multiple choice  ? (to pick the answer )

Comment: No sir I don't have it.

Comment: Name $Y=Y_0$  so $$Y_{n+1}=Y_{n}'$$