# MacLaurin Series of $\tan(x)$

Tags: trigonometry, power-series, taylor-expansion

I am trying to answer the following:

> Compute the MacLaurin series of $\tan(x)$.

I know this one is:
$$\tan x=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}2^{2n}(2^{2n}-1)B_{2n}x^{2n-1}}{(2n)!}$$
And I know how to derive this formula. Indeed I simply express $\tan$ as a linear combination of $\cot(x)$ and $\cot(2x)$, for which we know the explicit formula
$$\cot(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n2^{2n}B_{2n}x^{2n-1}}{(2n)!}$$
This formula is derived by writing $\cot$ in its exponential form and doing some algebra.

I know how to derive these formulas, but I do not understand what makes it the MacLaurin series for $\tan(x)$. Why couldn't they be any Taylor series centered somewhere else? And what even makes them a Taylor series, I only see it as a power series...

Thank you for you responses and help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because if we have a function $f\colon(a-r,a+r)\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ and a power series$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(x-a)^n\tag1$$centered at $a$ such that$$\bigl(\forall x\in(a-r,a+r)\bigr):f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(x-a)^n,$$then automatically $f$ is a $C^\infty$ function and its Taylor series centered at $a$ is $(1)$.

For instance,$$|x|<1\implies\frac1{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$$and therefore the Taylor series of $\frac1{1-x}$ centered at $0$ is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$.

Answer (score 1):

In order to expand the function $\tan x$ at any point $x_0\in\bigl(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\bigr)$, it is sufficient to give a general formula for the $n$th derivative of the function $\tan x$. Such a general formula can be alternatively given as follows.
\begin{gather*}
(\tan x)^{(n)}=-(\ln\cos x)^{(n+1)}\\
=-\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}(k-1)!}{(\cos x)^k} B_{n+1,k}\biggl(-\sin x,-\cos x,\sin x,\cos x,\dotsc, \cos\biggl[x+\frac{(n-k+2)\pi}{2}\biggr]\biggr)\\
=-\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac{(-1)^{k-1}(k-1)!}{(\cos x)^k} \frac{(-1)^k(\cos x)^k}{k!}\sum_{\ell=0}^k\binom{k}{\ell}\frac{(-1)^\ell}{(2\cos x)^\ell}
\sum_{q=0}^\ell\binom{\ell}{q}(2q-\ell)^{n+1} \cos\biggl[(2q-\ell)x+\frac{(n+1)\pi}2\biggr]\\
=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{k}\sum_{\ell=0}^k\binom{k}{\ell}\frac{(-1)^{\ell}}{(2\cos x)^\ell}
\sum_{q=0}^\ell\binom{\ell}{q}(2q-\ell)^{n+1} \cos\biggl[(2q-\ell)x+\frac{(n+1)\pi}2\biggr].
\end{gather*}
To the best of my knowledge, there are several other ways to compute the general formula of the $n$th derivative of the function $\tan x$ in the following, but not limited to, references.

References

1. Feng Qi and Miao-Miao Zheng, *Explicit expressions for a family of the Bell polynomials and applications*, Applied Mathematics and Computation **258** (2015), 597--607; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.amc.2015.02.027.
2. Feng Qi and Jacques Gelinas, *Revisiting Bouvier's paper on tangent numbers*, Advances and Applications in Mathematical Sciences **16** (2017), no. 8, 275--281.
3. Feng Qi and Bai-Ni Guo, *An explicit formula for derivative polynomials of the tangent function*, Acta Universitatis Sapientiae Mathematica **9** (2017), no. 2, 348--359; available online at https://doi.org/10.1515/ausm-2017-0026.
4. Feng Qi, *Derivatives of tangent function and tangent numbers*, Applied Mathematics and Computation **268** (2015), 844--858; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.amc.2015.06.123.
5. Chao-Ping Chen and Feng Qi, *A double inequality for remainder of power series of tangent function*, Tamkang Journal of Mathematics **34** (2003), no. 4, 351--355; available online at https://doi.org/10.5556/j.tkjm.34.2003.236.
6. Jiao-Lian Zhao, Qiu-Ming Luo, Bai-Ni Guo, and Feng Qi, *Remarks on inequalities for the tangent function*, Hacettepe Journal of Mathematics and Statistics **41** (2012), no. 4, 499--506.
7. Feng Qi, Da-Wei Niu, Dongkyu Lim, and Yong-Hong Yao, *Special values of the Bell polynomials of the second kind for some sequences and functions*, Journal of Mathematical Analysis and Applications **491** (2020), no. 2, Paper No. 124382, 31 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jmaa.2020.124382.
8. A.-M. Xu and G.-D. Cen, *Closed formulas for computing higher-order derivatives of functions involving exponential functions*, Appl. Math. Comput. **270** (2015), 136--141; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.amc.2015.08.051.
9. A.-M. Xu and Z.-D. Cen, *Some identities involving exponential functions and Stirling numbers and applications*, J. Comput. Appl. Math. **260** (2014), 201--207; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cam.2013.09.077.